# using SSL for Amazon lightsail

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to activate ssl for my websites that I have setup in Lightsail. As I am going to use SSL and lightsail doesn't offer SSL for single instance of server and I need to have multiple servers and then get load balancer and then get the SSL ( which is ridiculous ), I tried to get SSL from 1and1 and then load the certificate into lightsail IIS.

Importing SSL certification ( .cer ) file in IIS is successful and it even show it in the list of approved certificates, but when I try to add a web site in IIS, SSL Certificate list is still empty and when going back to IIS home page and click "Certificates", it has been removed from there.

Does it mean that amazon doesn't allow to import third party Certificates to be imported or there is some other issues.

Any advices would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in order to activate SSL in windows server IIS , I have to provide a ssl key that is generated using private key and I have to get that private key separately from my SSL provider and also set a password when creating ssl file.

this Private key enabled ssl file is different from regular .cer file that the ssl provider let you to download.

https://serverfault.com/questions/72297/ssl-certificates-disappear-iis